# intent to launch any website link if app is not installed

Tags: android, google-chrome, ionic-framework, android-intent, deep-linking

I am using this plugin in ionic 4 app to open app from URL

```
ionic cordova plugin add ionic-plugin-deeplinks --variable URL_SCHEME=myapp --variable DEEPLINK_SCHEME=https --variable DEEPLINK_HOST=example.com --variable ANDROID_PATH_PREFIX=/

npm install --save @ionic-native/deeplinks@4
```

I am using Intent for that. I followed [Deep App linking](https://paul.kinlan.me/deep-app-linking-on-android-and-chrome/)

```
<a href="intent:<url>/#Intent;scheme=myapp;package=com.packageName;S.browser_fallback_url=<url>;end">Open App</a>
```

it works when app is installed.

Issue is when app is not installed, it redirect user to play store directly to install app, but I want to open `<url>` instead of play store. I added `S.browser_fallback_url` and if app is not installed on device then it should fall back to the url but it does nothing.

Is it possible to open web url instead of play store or is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Did you encode the fallback URL (after `S.browser_fallback_url=`)?

Comment: @Thomas no...why and how to do that?

Comment: You can run it through `encodeURIComponent()` (in JS). The beginning should look like `https%3A%2F%2F`

Comment: @Thomas Yes..I tried the way you suggested ...fallback URL is not opening
I am getting `Navigation is blocked:` warning

https://codepen.io/rpragesh/pen/MWKjGBg